# force file download via amazon s3 php class

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My application is using [tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class](https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class) to put and get objects to/from Amazon S3 storage.

Files are not available publicly and I want my users to be able to download private files through my application.

*amazon-s3-php-class* offers two options to get the file:

1. Save an object to file: `S3::getObject($bucketName, $uploadName, $saveName)`
2. Save an object to a resource of any type: `S3::getObject($bucketName, $uploadName, fopen('savefile.txt', 'wb'))`

But both methods save a file to my web server. How can I force file download to a client's computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could use the second option, passing the output buffer as the filename argument for fopen (after setting the correct headers):

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
//etc etc

S3::getObject($bucketName, $uploadName, fopen('php://output', 'wb'));
```